# Атрибуты textarea

Tags: html

Здравствуйте. Как указать максимальную длину символов в тегах textarea?
Делала так: `<textarea name="meta_d" id="meta_d" cols="40" rows="10" maxlength="255"></textarea>` - вводится неограниченное количество символов. А с инпутом все нормально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В рамках HTML - никак, у textarea нет такого атрибута. Варианты:

1. Проверять длину введённого в `onsubmit()` формы
2. Вешать обработчик на нажатие клавиш, считать длину введённой строки и не принимать ввод, если больше (+ [комбинированый подход, с эмуляцией `maxlength`](http://www.jstoolbox.com/skripty/rabota-s-formami/ogranichenie-kolichestva-vvodimyx-simvolov-dlya-textarea/))

P.S. На самом деле вариант 2 - только для развлечения, так как он не реагирует на копипаст и выделение+удаление мышой.

Comment: На самом деле достаточно добавить обработку события `change` и это уже не развлечение, не?

Comment: Не. Потому как при мышепасте change не будет.

Comment: @klopp ок, раз change, blur вас не устраивает - oncopy, onpaste вам о чем-то говорит?

Comment: Говорит. Только ко мне-то какие претензии? Хочется развлекаться, отлавливая все события - пожалуйста :) Тем более что обрабатывать onpaste, например, задача не самая очевидная.

Comment: @klopp - "Тем более что обрабатывать onpaste, например, задача не самая очевидная", lolчто?

     $('textarea').on('paste', function() {
       var $el = $(this);
       setTimeout( function() {
         $el.trigger('change');
       })
     })

"Хочется развлекаться, отлавливая все события - пожалуйста :)" - издеваетесь? достаточно обработчика описанного выше + обработчиков change и keypress ( причем change не обязателен, он, скорее, для наглядности )

Comment: Я ещё раз спрашиваю: от меня что нужно-то? Направление указал, хочется развлечений - вперёд развивайте идею, а что для вас очевидно а что нет - мне неведомо...

Comment: От вас нужно не писать глупостей, собственно все

Answer (score 0):

С помощью JavaScript или jQuery. На jQuery очень легко реализовать.